# Html2pdf very slow with a lot of pages for one pdf

Tags: php, html, performance, pdf, html2pdf

I'm trying to create pdf from html using html2pdf (last version) in PHP. I have a lot of pages for one pdf & the creation of file is too slow.

For example, 6 minutes for only 26 pages & the pdf contains a small image for each page.

I can't split HTML because in html2pdf you can use only the function writeHtml.

- Is there someone that has the same problem?
- Has someone create a pdf with a lot of pages?
- Is a problem of class?
- Do you know a class to generate pdf from html that hasn't problem with a big number of pages?

Comment: 1. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: 2. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I can't print the code beacuse is too much long. I debug the html code with the function setModeDebug, but there aren't problem. I don't have any errors from the class. If I create a small pdf, with a few pages, it works perfectly and fast. If I create a pdf with a lot of pages, with the same html, the pdf is created without errors and problems but it takes time to generate it. I can't wait 20 minutes for a pdf with 50 pages, it's too much. I would like to know if there is someone that have used this class and found the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php

reference the above link. very simple create html to pdf.

---

**UPDATE**
New link: https://mpdf.github.io/

Comment: Thank you. Have you tested it with large pdf? what are the different between mpdf and html2pdf?

Comment: Wow, it's perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: Link is to a 404 page. Do you have an updated? Try to add the content in the answer if possible